# Why does my paypal minicart hide behind my navbar?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, navbar

I have created a paypal button using the JavaScript code as stated [here](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/) and have also used the paypal mini cart.

The cart works fine, but there is one problem. The cart hides behind my navbar when you scroll to the top of the page, when you are lower down, it works fine. I am using twitter bootstrap and a template. I'm not sure if its the bootstrap, or something I did with the buttons.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my first guess would be to check your if your navbar has z-index, its actualy hard to tell without code sample

Comment: Yeah I have now checked that and that was the problem, thanks for your help!